# Why dag runs more once when dagruns in Airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

This is my code:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2018,9,9),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG('hello', catchup=False, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=1))
```

And the task instances list is like this:
[image]

You can see that I started at 08:36:24, and I know it will execute the task at 08:35:20 since I set the schedule_interval equals 1 minute. But why it executed the task at 08:34:20?

Comment: this is something I am also very confused. Airflow does not work as it should or I am not yet capable to _figure it out_

Comment: I am trying to understand the DAG, do you want to run the DAG every minute from the start date?

Comment: @kaxil Yes, the problem is that it will always run one more time at beginning, which is really confused me. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Can upload the logs please?

Comment: @kaxil The log will help nothing for it is not an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rightmost column shows when the corresponding task was actually executed, but it does not tell us when you actually enabled the DAG. I suspect that you enabled the DAG when it was 08:35, the scheduler picked up the DAG and scheduled the first DAG run for 8:34. As the scheduler finished all the setup work and executed the first DAG run, it was already 8:36.

The one minute interval was simply too short (or you was too slow ;)). Try a 10 minute interval and enable the DAG when it is, for example, 8:33 (so not at the scheduling interval boundary, such as 8:30 or 8:40) and you will see that everything works as you expect.

Comment: Yes. You are right. It was normal when I set the interval as 1 day.

Comment: Haha, to be honest, I have fixed this problem already before you provide this answer. But I still choose to accept it !